# generation slow pdf (yii framework)

Tags: php, svg, pdf-generation, yii, libpng

i reviewed similar questions, but not found solution for my problem

Environment of our web-project using:

- List item
- yii framework (Zend Engine v2.3.0)
- php 5.3.8
- server os Fedora15
- java 1.6.0_22
- Apache Batik 1.7 java lib
- libpng 2:1.2

Our project generate dynamicaly pdf documents (using Zend Pdf class).

PDF generation takes arout **~10 seconds** to complete for about **2 pages**, which include 2 png-images (charts sending in POST data on svg format and java converted him (svg) to png image; on web charts generated with highcharts js-lib, to png ).

We need speed up generation process.

some parts of our code:

```
public function actionQuery()
{
     ...
     $xxExporter->generatePdf($request, $someAdditionalData);
     ...
     $xxExporter->httpOutputFile();
     ...
     Yii::app()->end();
}

public function generatePdf(CHttpRequest $request, array $someAdditionalData)
{
    initRequest($request, $someAdditionalData);
    ...
    ...attachItemToPdf..
    ...
    setMetaData
    ...
}

public function httpOutputFile()
{
    $this->pdf->save($filename);

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$this->filename}.pdf\"");
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($filename));

    echo file_get_contents($filename);
    unlink($filename);
}
```

converting svg to png with java:

```
$type = "-m {$this->fileType}";
$width = !empty($this->fileExportWidth) ? "-w {$this->fileExportWidth}" : '';
$outputFile = "-d {$this->fileExportTempName}";
$inputFile = $this->fileTempName;

$errorString = exec("{$this->pathJava} -jar {$this->pathBatik} {$type} {$outputFile} {$indexed} {$width} {$inputFile}", $output, $return_var);
```

Tomorrow i will try to install some jpg-lib to server, and try replace png to jpg in project.

if you need some additional information - let me know, I give it to you.

Could someone help me? I really don't know how to do this, I've tried everything I know.

Thank you very much for any help or suggestions!!

Comment: You should profile it more and see which is the slow process, if the image convertion or the pdf creation; you might also want to test both processes using less datas to see if the problem lies there.

Comment: i found trouble parts on export function: i have 2 charts, they generated very slowly, about 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://www.princexml.com/ - it works very fast and it's very easy.